# I'm getting an error when I use negative floating point numbers in my power function

Tags: floating-point, ocaml, pow

For my `float_pow` function, when I test with a negative x, like using the code `float_pow (-2.5) 2`, I get this error message:

> "Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int".

But if I do `float_pow (-.2.5) 2`, then the code actually works. How do I change my code so that I don't need to put a period after the dash?

```
let rec float_pow x n =
    if n < 0 then
        0.
    else if n = 0 then
        1.
    else
        x *. float_pow x (n - 1);;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your reported problem. When I enter your code, the expresion `float_pow (-2.5) 2` evaluates to 6.25. You might try starting up the toplevel from scratch and trying again. Note that if you leave out the parentheses you *will* get your reported error. The parentheses in `(-2.5)` are necessary.

Comment: Could it possibly be due to the version of Ocaml? Because I'm testing my code on https://try.ocamlpro.com/ which is using version 4.01.0.

Comment: FWIW `(-2.5)` works in v4.02.1

Comment: Almost certinaly this is not due to your ocaml version. Could you copy/paste your exact input and output?

Comment: The error seems to be specific to try.ocamlpro.com itself. It might be better to use sketch.sh which is far more up-to-date.